# UWP Custom Control, Can't Use Binding, only x:Bind, How To Adapt?

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, uwp

I have created a custom control in UWP, but the issue I have exists on Microsoft provided custom controls as well, so I'll use the UWP Community Toolkit OrbitView as an example.  The following 3 bindings work:

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyProperty}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind PageViewModel.MyProperty, Mode=OneWay}"/>
    <Toolkit:OrbitView MinItemSize="{x:Bind PageViewModel.MyProperty, Mode=OneWay}" />
</Grid>
```

The standard control (TextBlock) works with either Binding or x:Bind.  But if I want to use Binding on the custom control:

```
<Toolkit:OrbitView MinItemSize="{Binding MyProperty}" />
```

It does not.  Searching here and the web I'm struggling to figure out what's going on and why. The general solution seems to be to just use x:Bind.  However I want to put my custom control inside a UserControl because I want the option for it to be loaded from an external Xaml file at runtime using XamlReader. My understanding is you can't use x:Bind in this situation as that needs to be there at compile time. Is there any solution to accomplish what I'm after in UWP?

Comment: This is odd because the custom control should have the same DataContext.  Just for testing could you point to the DataContext on the custom control to the ViewModel supplied and try that also i.e. ```<Toolkit:OrbitView DataContext={Binding} />``` or something like that. You're right in thinking it should work so I'm not sure what's going on here. I will say that if x:Bind is working you're probably better off using that instead as it's faster.

Comment: It absolutely does have the same DataContext which is why I put in the TextBlock to demonstrate.  I'm not even testing it in a UserControl, this is in MainPage.Xaml. I'm not sure it's supposed to work.  I think Binding requires the DependencyProperty targets to be pre-compiled or something of that nature, which would explain why custom controls don't work.  As for why I don't just use x:Bind I explained my dilemma.  If you can think of a workaround or know how to get x:Bind to work in a UserControl it would be much appreciated and would be an acceptable workaround.

Comment: And just for clarification when I say it doesn't work, I mean the setter on the custom control's dependency property wrapper isn't even firing.

Comment: Setters on DependencyControl properties don't fire when using binding. Binding takes the DependencyObject lookup SetValue method and binds to it directly. DepenendencyObjects are they're own bread.

Comment: And as for the textblock, I understand the DataContext there is the same but I can't see why the Toolkit:OrbitView wouldn't see it. How are you deciding it's not binding? What on the OrbitView isn't working? I'm only asking because if you're looking at the setter for binding, as I mentioned, you won't see it there.

Comment: Another work around, which shouldn't be this way, is to just xBind to the DataContext. ```<Toolkit:OrbitView DataContext="{x:Bind PageViewModel}" />
```  This way your internal UserControl 'should' still bind to the DataContext as usual. I admit that even if this fixes it I would like to know and understand why it isn't working to start with. I'm almost certain that should be working the way you have it with ```<Toolkit:OrbitView MinItemSize="{Binding MyProperty}" />``` Technically, you're doing it right so I'm confused. Post the OrbitView XAML also please.

Comment: Dependency property wrappers fire with x:Bind.  You're saying they don't fire with Binding, that that would explain a lot since that's what I've been using to see if it's working.  My dp wrapper setters run other code in the custom control so that's why they never worked, and for the OrbitView I just put a break point on a setter and watched it fire with x:Bind but not with Binding.  So I think the mystery here is solved, thank you. I did figure out how to use x:Bind in a UserControl, so I guess I'll just do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, well here's why it wasn't working if you're running other code in the setter and how to get it to work.

Here's the proper way to implement a dependency property and have code execute on the setter.  This was done in UWP project, since you're question is UWP, but has the exact same principles for all dependency properties of any project type.

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage() => InitializeComponent();        

    public int SomeValue
    {
        get => (int)GetValue(SomeValueProperty);
        set => SetValue(SomeValueProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SomeValueProperty = //Notice this is static. It's bound to an internal static hash table of some sort; I use to know exactly but forgot.
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(SomeValue), /*The name of the property to register against. 
                               * The static version is always the name of the property ended with Property
                               * i.e. SomeValue property is SomeValueProperty dependency property */                                                 
            typeof(int), //This is the type used to describe the property.
            typeof(MainPage), //This is the type the dependency property relates to. 

            /* Below this is the magic. It's where we supply the property meta data and can be delivered different ways.
            * For this example I will supply only the default value and the event we want to use when the value is changed.
            * Note: 
            * The event we supply is fired ONLY if the value is changed. This event is what we need to use to handle changes in the setter to cover binding operations as well. */
            new PropertyMetadata(default(int),  /* This is the default value the dependency property will have. 
                                                * It can be whatever you decide but make sure it works with the same type or you'll most likely get an error. */

                /* This is the event fired when the value changes.
                 * Note: Dependency properties binding and events always operate on the UI thread. Cross threading will throw exceptions. */
                new PropertyChangedCallback((s, e) =>
                {
                    var mainPage = s as MainPage; //The sender of the callback will always be of the type it's from.

                    /* The values given from the e argument for OldValue and NewValue should be of type int in this example...
                     * but since we can't gaurantee the property is setup properly before here I always add a check. */
                    if (e.OldValue is int oldValue) { }
                    if (e.NewValue is int newValue) 
                    { 
                         /* Now do what you want with the information.  This is where you need to do custom work instead of using the setter.
                          * Note: If you need to work on something in the MainPage remember this is a static event and you'll need to refer to the sender or s value in this case.
                          * I've converted s to the variable mainPage for easy referencing here. */
                         mainPage.MyCustomControl.Value = newValue;  //Note: The custom control should bind to this as well via XAML making this pointless. I set the value here just for educational purposes.
                    }
                })));

}
```

A dependency property shouldn't look this scary, and really isn't, but I've added a lot of comments to help you navigate through it a little easier.  hopefully this helps :)

Comment: I'm going to rework my custom control to not use the wrapper setters and use this instead.  Thanks!

Comment: No problem; glad to help. Reviewed the profile also, keep up the good work.