# UWP Display can not update TextBlock value when changed

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have UserControl that contains a TextBlock.
I add this UserControl into MainPage, then update TextBlock every 1 seconds.
I debug and see that TextBlock value is changed, but display is undisplayed.
Is there anything wrong in my code?

MyDialog.xaml

```
<UserControl
    ...
    d:DesignHeight="100"
    d:DesignWidth="200">

    <Grid>
        <TextBlock x:Name="forTestDisplay" FontSize="16" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                   Text="{Binding ForTest, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

MyDialog.xaml.cs

```
namespace Test_UserControl
{
    public sealed partial class MyDialog : UserControl
    {
        public MyDialog()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        // Dependency Property for binding
        public string ForTest
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(ForTestProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ForTestProperty, value); }
        }
        
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ForTestProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ForTest", typeof(string), typeof(MyDialog), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    }
}
```

MainPage.xaml

```
<Page
    ...
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid>
        <local:MyDialog x:Name="myDialog" />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
namespace Test_UserControl
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        private DispatcherTimer timer;

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            timer = new DispatcherTimer();
            timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
            timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
            timer.Start();
        }

        private void Timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
        {
            // Update the data in MyDialog
            myDialog.ForTest = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is recommended to use **{x:bind}** in UserControl.

For **x:bind**, the DataContext is current page, it will find the property in the current Code-Bebind class. But for **Binding**, assumes, by default, that you're binding to the DataContext of your markup page.

You can refer to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76865080/cant-get-binding-to-work-when-moving-to-usercontrol/76868147#76868147), and there are XAML Binding Failures Window in Visual Studio and Top tips on APP when debugging.

Comment: Work!!,  I changed to Text="{x:Bind ForTest, Mode=OneWay}" in MyDialog.xaml. Thanks you very much!

Comment: @rickyrocky If someone solves your issue, please [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: Oh, I forgot this. I accepted the answer.